# LESSCSS method with IE FIlter Alpha Opacity CSS

Tags: css, less

I am using [LESSCSS](http://lesscss.org/).  I'm trying to create a method for opacity:

```
.opacity (@opacity) 
{
    opacity: @opacity;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(@opacity * 100))"; 
    filter: alpha(opacity = (@opacity * 100));
}
```

So, If I call it using:

```
h1 {
  .opacity(.5);
}
```

I want it to output:

```
h1 {
  opacity: .5;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
}
```

But instead, LESS throws the error:

```
Expected '}' on line 30 in file '/Content/styles/style.less.css':
 [29]:     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(@opacity * 100))"; 
 [30]:     filter: alpha(opacity = (@opacity * 100));
       ----^
 [31]: }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In dotless, do this. (I would NOT recommend script tags - they are ugly, language specific and not supported by dotless).

```
.opacity (@opacity) {
    @opacityPercentage: @opacity * 100;
    opacity: @opacity;
    -ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(@{opacityPercentage}))"; 
    filter: ~"alpha(opacity = (@{opacityPercentage}))";
}
```

in dotless 1.2.3 (when it is released in a couple of weeks, or github head, you should be able to do this...

```
.opacity (@opacity) {
    @opacityPercentage: @opacity * 100;
    opacity: @opacity;
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(@opacityPercentage)); 
    filter: alpha(opacity = (@opacityPercentage));
}
```

and re: the comment from Mathletics, dotless is not "the worst compiler".. It matches less.js up to 1.1.5, soon to be 1.2.2 and many of the 600 bugs against less.js are fixed in dotless. You may have used dotless over 8 months ago, but things change and bugs are fixed... dotless also has better support for comments and variable scoping.

Comment: You still need to escape the filter expressions for valid LESS, though I do like the way you're handling the multiplication.

Comment: This only worked for me after removing the parenthesis around opacity = (@opacityPercentage).

Comment: dotless == less? I'm confused.

Answer (score 11):

You need to prefix the string with `~`, like so:

```
-ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)";
```

From the docs: [Escaping](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping)

UPDATE: you need to wrap the variable names in curly braces.

```
.opacity (@opacity) {
    opacity: @opacity;
    -ms-filter: ~`"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(" + "@{opacity}" * 100 + "))"`; 
    filter: ~`"alpha(opacity = (" + "@{opacity}" * 100 + "))"`;
}
```

Here's what's happening: after the prefix, wrap the entire expression in backticks so that it is evaluated as JavaScript. Then you can add the result of the multiplication to the rest of the string; you also need to wrap the LESS variable in quotes and curly braces so the compiler can evaluate it before the multiplication.

This has been a cool question; I didn't actually know LESS could do this.

Comment: please see my edit above.. escaping the string still did not solve the problem

Comment: Read the next section on evaluating JS in the docs. You are reading the docs, right?

Comment: Read it like 10 times, still not understanding how that can solve my problem.

Comment: see my updated answer? It shows that you need to wrap your variable names in curly braces, like `@{opacity}` when they are inside a string.

Comment: That did help with resolving the variable, but Its not doing the multiplication.. im wondering if its even possible. See my edit above

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the solution but.. This still did not solve my problem.. Because I'm rendering the LESS file on the server and not on the client so.. the javascript evaluations dont work. :(  so, I might just have to do some ugly solution to get this working.. by passing the method 2 variables..

Comment: Thank you though for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your LESS compiler, not the JS evals. I tested using this: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler and it worked.

Comment: I'm using DotLess : http://www.dotlesscss.org/ which could be the reason it cant do JS evaluations.. not 100% sure though.

Comment: DotLess is the worst of the compilers that I've seen. That's definitely your problem.

Answer (score 6):

This might help someone :)

```
.opacity(@a : 0.8)
{
    zoom:1;
    opacity: @a;
    -moz-opacity: @a;
    -ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(@{a} * 100))"; 
    filter:~"alpha(opacity= @{a} * 100)";
}
```

Comment: putting alpha in the quotes helped me when LESS wasn't compiling because it thought alpha was a function.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the curly brackets. Edited the answer please check. :)

Comment: its ok.  i didn't need it as a parametric mixin per se, but rather for just getting the correct syntax within LESS.

Comment: This does NOT work! it will be something like: `filter:alpha(opacity= 0.8 * 100);` instead of `filter:alpha(opacity=80);`

Answer (score 5):

There is nice solution I found in internet - [LESS CSS class for cross browser opacity](http://freestyle-developments.co.uk/blog/?p=400):

```
.opacity(@opacity) {

     @ieOpacity: @opacity * 100;
     -ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=@{ieOpacity})"; // IE 8
     filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{ieOpacity})"; // IE 5-7
     opacity: @opacity;
}
```

Comment: This was the correct solution for me, because all other solutions threw an extra set of parens around the `-ms-filter` opacity value.. causing it to fail for me.

Comment: All these methods with mixins are quite bad for me now. The best way to manage such properties is using set of javascript task manager (grunt, gulp) with autoprefixer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

naaa .. 
this one worked for me:

```
.opacity(@a:0.5){
    zoom:1;
    opacity: @a;
    -moz-opacity: @a;
    @iea : @a*100;
    -ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=(@{iea}))";
    filter:~"alpha(opacity= @{iea})";
}
```